# Redirect only oldsite.com to newsite.com, but not include the oldsite.com/wp-login.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need some help on how to redirect a specific URL into another URL.

Let's say I enter oldsite.com and it will redirect to newsite.com. Inside oldsite.com I installed Wordpress, but when I accessed oldsite.com/wp-login.php it redirects me to newsite.com and show a 404 error. I only need to redirect the oldsite.com to newsite.com and *WILL NOT* redirect when I access oldsite.com/wp-login.php

Here's the code I'm using inside my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Hope someone can help. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RewriteCond` directive to exclude the page you don't want to redirect :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-login.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Your css file is also redirecting to the new domain. You can exclude it using the exact same directive as you used to exclude the `wp-login.php` . put the following condition line above your RewriteRule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/file\.css$`